# Using Spring Data Neo4j outside of Spring container

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Can Spring Data Neo4j be used "standalone" (i.e. outside Spring container) like Spring Data JPA can?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot use Spring Data Neo4j outside of a Spring Container as it does not integrate with the [CDI integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpd.misc.cdi-integration) support in [Spring Data Commons](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/commons) yet.

Feel free to open a [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH) issue if you'd like to see support for that.